# Is steering wheel free play a simple adjustment?

Tags: steering

I just replaced my rack and pinion steering gear with a "brand new" remanufactured unit from a reputable builder.

Manual steering unit.  No hydraulic power assist.

I notice the steering wheel has about 5 degrees of effortless "free play" (slop) with audible clicks when it reaches end of travel.  It has exactly the same amount of free play in any front wheel position, i.e. the free play is uniform all along the rack.

I also noticed (from postmortem on the old gear) that there is a fairly easy "free play" adjustment behind the pinion.

Will that adjustment correct it?

Is it normal/expected for a mechanic replacing steering gear to make that adjustment as part of the work?

Given that it's a "new" remanufactured unit with a lifetime warranty, I don't want to void the warranty.

Comment: Ask your mechanic about it. He might adjust it for free because he installed it.

Comment: This sounds like the poster did the work themself @Jupiter.

Comment: Please include the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question. ***EVERY*** car is different and therefore there's a different answer. Without the rudimentary knowledge of what you're asking about, there's no way to answer this properly.

Comment: Are you sure the play isn’t in the steering column universal joints?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes, because I didn't change the universal joints, just the steering gear, and the old gear did not do that.

Comment: I would suggest that the first thing you should do is contact the seller and ask their advice, just in case you do void the warranty.